# Postgresql 9.6 only one database need to replicated. (single database replication)

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, postgresql-9.6

I am new to PostgreSQL, I am trying to replicate single database like only one database need to replicate from Master to Slave Server.

Comment: Can you put there your SQL example code ?

Comment: This is not possible with 9.6 without additional tools, like e.g.: https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/resources/pglogical/  with the upcoming Version 10 this will be possible with built-in tools: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/logical-replication.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find more information here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/logical-replication.html

I am not sure without a sample code (from your side) what is your code/error/etc.